# Load Angular library on specific pages

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, requirejs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to integrate Angular in to parts of my web application. When i say parts, i mean there are a number of pages with either just static text or images which it does not make sense to load a +100kb library, especially as many users will be using a mobile device.

I am currently using requireJS.. Is there a way i can only load Angular when a specific page/s are laoded, for example:

```
Home.html:                Angular Not Required
Contact Us.html:          Angular Not Required
About Us.html:            Angular Not Required
Product.html:             **Angular Required**
Order.html:               **Angular Required**
Order Confirmation.html:  Angular Not Required
Our Offices.html:         Angular Not Required
```

At the moment, i am loading Angular in my main.js file using:

```
(function(require) {
'use strict';

require.config({
    baseUrl: '/resources/js',
    paths: {
        .......
        .......
        .......
    },
    shim: {
        .......
        .......
        .......
    }
});


require(['angular', 'myApp'], function (angular, myApp) {
    angular.bootstrap(document,['myApp']);
});

})(this.require);
```

Ideally i would like to achieve this without including script tags in the HTML.

Thanks

Comment: There is [this effort](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy) to intergate Require lazy + Angular. Have not tried your case but **maybe** this would work: Define `angular` as lazy dependency: `require(['lazy!angular',...],function(angularProxy,...){...})` and when you actually need it do: `angularProxy.get().then(function(angular) { angular.bootstrap(...); } ...`. Also check [require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy).

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos - Thanks for the links Nikos - do you have a working jsFiddle at all?

Comment: I do not have a fiddle; require-lazy has several examples though, you can check them out in the [examples](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy/tree/master/examples) folder; just `git clone` it and run `npm install` for the simple examples to get the feeling. Again I have not tried your specific case, so I cannot tell if it will work for you.